# Google NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.ttf contains gujarati ,hindi,urdu letters but it didnt appear in PDF

Tags: fonts, cjk, google-noto

I have converted NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf to NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.ttf.

As per Guideline on https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/ "Each font sets one language as the default. Note that each language-specific font does support all four languages and includes the complete set of glyphs".when i opened this converted ttf file in FontForge,i can see gujarati,hindi,arabic letters but when i given this file to PDF rendering it is not showing on PDF file.however all other letters like chinese,japanese,korean,english letters displayed correctly.

can anyone help if i am missing something?

Comment: Yeah: the CJK fonts do not support those scripts at all, so either you're not loading the font you say you are, or you're misreading what FontForge is showing you (FF will show shows you a placeholder boxes for every single Unicode code points, including the ones that aren't implemented at all, unless you tell FF to compact the glyph set), There are no characters in the CJK versions of Noto other than all the blocks required to support CJKV.

Comment: Oh,i have misread it.its showing me X sign on missing glyphs and possible character below that.i just want to add that glyphs on that position..let me google.thanks a lot.

Comment: Why? Just get another font that does support the characters you need, and use a font stack in whatever you're actually using the font in. There are literally Noto Gujarati, Noto Devanagari, and _several_ Arabic versions depending on the form or arabic you need. Or Urdu, if you actually need that, for that matter. https://www.google.com/get/noto/

Comment: i need a whole bunch of glyphs in a single file just like ArialUnicodeMs.ttf.

Comment: No, you don't - what makes you claim you do?